# SQL Get row that have maximum values over two columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this in Snowflake. It supports ANSI SQL, so don't worry if this DB isn't familiar to you.

| Salesman | Customer | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brown | Super Company | UK |
| Brown | Another customer | UK |
| Smith | Contoso | US |
| Brown | Test company | US |

I'd need to find where each salesman have most of customers. So desired response for the query would be like this.

| Salesman | Country | cnt(country) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Brown | UK | 2 |
| Smith | US | 1 |

I've come up with this

```
SELECT
   salesman,
   country,
   max(count(country))
FROM
   customertable
GROUP BY
   salesman, country
```

But nested aggeregation functions aren't supported. And I've already read quite good reasons for that. But I just cannot find a way to do that in any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QUALIFY` could be used to filter the highest value per `salesman`:

```
SELECT salesman,
       country,
       count(country) AS cnt
FROM customertable
GROUP BY salesman, country
QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY salesman ORDER BY cnt DESC) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your questions i guess you would want to count customer by country instead of country.
This should do the job with the use of **WINDOW FUNCTIONS** AND **QUALIFY**
[Window Functions documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE customers (salesman STRING, customer STRING, country STRING);

INSERT INTO customers
VALUES
('Brown', 'Super Company', 'UK'),
('Brown', ' Another customer', 'UK'),
('Smith', 'Contoso', 'US'),
('Brown', 'Test company', 'US')
;

SELECT
    salesman,
    country,
    COUNT(customer) AS nb_customer
FROM customers
GROUP BY
    salesman,
    country
QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY salesman ORDER BY nb_customer DESC) = 1
;
```

Comment: I think both `count(customer)` and `count(country)` gives the same answer. It counts number of rows after all.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation reference, by the way.