# How to select rows based on properties of another row?

Tags: postgresql

Had a question..

```
| a_id | name | r_id | message        | date
_____________________________________________
|  1   | bob  | 77   | bob here       | 1-jan
|  1   | bob  | 77   | bob here again | 2-jan
|  2   | jack | 77   | jack here.     | 2-jan
|  1   | bob  | 79   | in another room| 3-feb
|  3   | gill | 79   | gill here      | 4-feb
```

These are basically accounts (`a_id)`  chatting inside different rooms (`r_id`)

I'm trying to find the last chat message for every room that `jack a_id = 2` is chatting in.
What i've tried so far is using `distinct on (r_id) ... ORDER BY r_id, date DESC`.

But this incorrectly gives me the last message in every room instead of only giving the last message in everyroom that ***jack*** belongs to.

```
|  2   | jack | 77   | jack here.     | 2-jan
|  3   | gill | 79   | gill here      | 4-feb
```

Is this a `partition` problem instead distinct on?

Comment: You can use `EXISTS` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68577573/sql-get-row-that-have-maximum-values-over-two-columns

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

- to group the rows by `r_id` with a `GROUP BY` clause
- to select only the groups where `a_id = 2` is included with a `HAVING` clause which aggregates the `a_id` of each group : `HAVING array_agg(a_id) @> array[2]`
- to select the latest message of each selected group by aggregating its rows in an array with `ORDER BY date DESC` and selecting the first element of the array : `(array_agg(t.*))[1]`
- to convert the selected rows into a json object and then displaying the expected result by using the `json_populate_record` function

The full query is :

```
SELECT (json_populate_record(null :: my_table, (array_agg(to_json(t.*)))[1])).*
  FROM my_table AS t
 GROUP BY r_id
 HAVING array_agg(a_id) @> array[2]
```

and the result is :

| a_id | name | r_id | message | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | 77 | bob here | 2022-01-01 |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3IIoyDbG)

Answer (score 0):

For last message in every chat room simply would be:

```
select a_id, name, r_id,  to_char(max(date),'dd-mon')  from chats 
where a_id =2
group by r_id, a_id,name;
```

Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/keCReoaXg2eScrhFetEq1b/0

Or seeing messages

```
with last_message as (
select a_id, name, r_id, to_char(max(date),'dd-mon') date  from chats 
where a_id =1
group by r_id, a_id,name 
)
select l.*, c.message 
from last_message l 
join chats c on (c.a_id= l.a_id and l.r_id=c.r_id and l.date=to_char(c.date,'dd-mon'));
```

Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/keCReoaXg2eScrhFetEq1b/1

Though all this complication could by avoided with a primary key on your table.